# Chrome loads 2 images in <picture> HTML5

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have view port ~1200px and picture container has 180px. This code:

```
<picture>
    <img srcset="img_180.jpg 180w, img_350.jpg 350w" src="img_350.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

loads `img_350.jpg`. Why it happens if image container is 180px?

Okey, maybe I have to set `sizes` attribute. My picture container is 180px if view port is > 576px, else it has 100% width. So this code:

```
<picture>
    <img sizes="(min-width: 576px) 180px, 100vw" srcset="img_180.jpg 180w, img_350.jpg 350w" src="img_350.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

loads both `img_180.jpg` and `img_350.jpg`. How to fix this? I need to load `img_180.jpg` only if user has > 576px view port, else load `img_350.jpg`, because if <= 576 px picture container has 100% width.

You might think because `img_350.jpg` loads automatically from `src`, but that's not right, because I added `<source ... type="image/webp">` and it loaded `img_180.webp` and `img_350.webp` (no `.jpg`).

https://jsfiddle.net/wLprbk7j/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have both src and srcset defined. Remove src attribute. This will let browsers calculate the src based on srcset and media queries. Browser will then automatically load the correct image.

As a fallback, remember to include [picturefill.js](https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have already said that if I add other source like `webp`, then no `.jpg` images loaded, so it does not depend. Plus removing `src` is not W3C valid.

Comment: Chrome supports webp format. When it sees that a webp format is available it prefers loading that because it is a compressed format. What’s wrong loading webp if you have your image in that format? Also, just because you didn’t manually add a src attribute and was calculated by browser doesn’t mean your page is not W3C valid. I recommend reading this article on Picture tag for its usage: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-html5-picture-for-responsive-images--cms-21015